# Кастомное View из двух TextView

Tags: android, android-customview

Хочу сделать кастомное View: Внутри RelativeLayout находятся два TextView  их хочу потом позиционировать в коде:  установить отступы, изменить размер шрифта. Доку почитал но кое что  мне так и не понятно: нужно ли прописывать файл атрибутов - если мне в принципе достаточно  и стандартных  свойств, как добраться до самих  елементов TextView  и установить им нужные свойства?

Я привел ниже код я это пытался сделать но на экране так ничего и не отобразилось. в чем проблема?

#### attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomItemView">

    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

#### custom_view.xml

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/customRelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mainWord"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"

    />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondWord"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainWord"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="29dp"
    android:text="sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"

    />

</merge>
```

#### CustomItemView.java

```
public class CustomItemView extends RelativeLayout {

private TextView mainWord;
private TextView secondWord;

private Context mContext;

public CustomItemView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);


    View  view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view,this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    mainWord = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainWord);
    secondWord = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.secondWord);

    mainWord.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mainWord.setText("Word");
    mainWord.setTextSize(59);
    secondWord.setText("Second");
    mainWord.setTextSize(59); }

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

}
```

#### activity.java

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        MyScreenSize.getPexelSize(TestActivity.this, getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

#### activity_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.attrakti.englishfor.customs.ColorOptionsView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="?android:attr/listDivider"
tools:context=".test.customs.TestActivity">

<com.MyProject.test.customs.CustomItemView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:onClick="onClicked"

    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mainWord.setAllCaps(typedArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomItemView_android_textAllCaps, false));
```

**attr.xml**

`<declare-styleable name="CustomItemView">
    <attr name="android:textAllCaps"/>
</declare-styleable>`

Comment: можно поподробней -  что  это за метод и как он решает мою задачу

Comment: Это на примере свойства "textAllCaps" у TexView использования атрибутов для установки параметров из разметки, если планируете все делать из кода, то достаточно LayoutInlfater и findViewById(), attr.xml можете не трогоать

Comment: Еще, у класcа View есть метод inflate(Context context, int layoutResId); можете использовать его вместо 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, null);

Comment: я там обновил код, делаю так как вы говорите, но ничего, что  я упускаю?

Comment: Конечно, вы используете CustomItemView в разметке, а это значит что при создании объекта CustomItemView вызывается конструктор 
public CustomItemView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, 
}
Его вам и нужно переопределить

Comment: Вот так все должно работать
`public CustomItemView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
  super(context, attrs);
  
  final View v = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);
  
  mainWord = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mainWord);
  secondWord = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.secondWord);


  mainWord.setText("Word");
  mainWord.setTextSize(59);
  secondWord.setText("Second");
  mainWord.setTextSize(59);
 }`

Comment: Кидает ошибку  Error:(27, 63) error: incompatible types:CustomItemView cannot be converted to ViewGroup
        final View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);

Comment: View v = inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this);  замените на inflate(context, R.layout.custom_view, this); и v.findViewById(R.id.mainWord); на findViewById(R.id.mainWord); и радуйтесь жизни)

Comment: так а оно все равно подчеркивает слово 'this' ошибка остается таже, оно как не принимало третий аргумент так и не принимает

Comment: Вам нужно наследовать ваш класс от RelativeLayout или ViewGroup, а не от View, если наследуетесь от RelativeLayout в разметке custom_view? можете заменить тег RelativeLayout на merge что бы избежать лишней вложенности

Comment: исправил на VIewGroup - ошибка пропала, попробывал поменять цвет бэкграунда -  и оно поменяла , но текстовые поля не видно

Comment: Сделайте RelativeLayout, все должно работать

Comment: кидает Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.test.customs.CustomItemView  это  в  activity_test .xml  в том месте где я определяю свой кастомный елемент

Comment: Выложите свой новый код, надо смотреть

Comment: изменил в разметке Relative  на merge  и ошибка пропала, но все равно не отображаются ТехtVew.  обновил код custom_view.xml  и CustomItemView.java

Comment: Этот код работает:
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

 private final TextView mMainWord, mSecondWord;

 public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  init(context, attrs, 0);
 }

 protected void init(Context context) {
  inflate(context, R.layout.layout.custom_view, this);

  setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  
  mMainWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainWord);
  mSecondWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondWord);
  
  // ... ваши действия с TextView
 }
}

Comment: @MrFist я наверное сойду с ума. Не отображается текст в TextView... 
У вас все отображается нормаль?

Comment: + super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

Comment: наконец то, это победа :)

Answer (score 2):

Файл атрибутов используется тогда, когда в вашем кастомном view предполагается использование кастомных атибутов

В вашем случае можно просто определить еще один конструктор

```
public CustomItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```

Чтобы добраться до элементов нужно использовать LayoutInlfater и findViewById()

Чтобы разобраться почитайте статьи про android compound view.

**UPDATE**

Не вызывается супер метод, нужно сделать так

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
}
```